# Java MySQL How to select rows within a ResultSet?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I have a very basic MySQL Database. This is the query I used to create it:

```
CREATE TABLE SC_Users(
ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
PRIMARY KEY (ID), 
Username varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
Class varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

I get a ResultSet by querying my database with this:

```
SELECT * FROM SC_Users
```

I want to be able to search for a username and then find the corresponding class of that username. How would I do this without using a different query?

I know its possible to find it easily by using:

```
SELECT * FROM SC_Users WHERE `Username` = Username
```

But I would prefer to use only 1 query if possible to find any value of a user I want.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You can achieve it by retrieving all your data in a `ResultSet`, then add all the values in a `List<MyClass>` only if they meet the conditions you need.

Comment: Why would you want to get all that data from the database and spend all that time in java iterating over it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `PreparedStatement` for your purpose.

```
    PreparedStatement pst=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    String userName = "someUser";
    String userClass;
    pst=con.prepareStatement("select * from SC_users where Username=? ");
    pst.setString(1,userName);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next())
        {
            userClass=rs.getString("Class");
        }
```